# Countif from multiple lists

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Right now I have a working formula

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF(C2,"*"&$O$2:$O$13&"*")), "Yes", "")
```

It prints "Yes" if a string in column C matches a string in a list in column O.

However, I now have 2 lists, list A and list B, and now I need to be able to print "No" if a cell in column C matches any of the strings in list B, and if in neither list A or B, to print something like "NA".

I haven't been able to figure out the formula further than just the one list. Any help is appreciated.

I threw together a painfully simple version of what I am getting at, where "Jersey Color" is being populated by the formula, and "Team Red/Blue" are the lists.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a data example? the input and expected output

Comment: Check out VLOOKUP: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Comment: Added a small table that should suffice as an example data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below formula in `B2` cell.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,C:C,0)),"RED",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,D:D,0)),"BLUE","NA"))
```

Answer (score 1):

This loops through all the players and finds if they are matched to a team.

```
Cells.Clear

'data
For i = 1 To 20
    Cells(i, 1) = Chr(64 + i)
Next i
For i = 1 To 20 Step 4
    Cells((i + 3) / 4, 3) = Chr(64 + i + Int(Rnd * 2))
    Cells((i + 3) / 4, 4) = Chr(66 + i + Int(Rnd * 2))
Next i

'code
Dim Players As Range, TeamA As Range, TeamB As Range
Set Players = Range("A1:A20")
Set TeamA = Range("C1:C5")
Set TeamB = Range("D1:D5")

Players.Offset(0, 1) = "N/A"
Players.Offset(0, 1).Font.Bold = True

Dim member As Range, player As Range

For Each player In Players

    For Each member In TeamA
        If member = player Then
            player.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 100, 100)
            player.Offset(0, 1) = "RED"
        End If
    Next member

    For Each member In TeamB
        If member = player Then
            player.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(100, 100, 255)
            player.Offset(0, 1) = "BLUE"
        End If
    Next member

Next player
```

Output:

[image: shirt colours]

Comment: This works great! Thank you for adding the color coding too:) Very helpful, and you thank you for expertise.